# Multiple classes in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes time to answer this. I'm learning Keras and got stuck with a problem where I have 3 classes and the  test set accuracy moves up to 0.6667 and then stalls on that exact number for 50 epochs. The accuracy is also way higher than what it should be if it were correct. This worked fine when I only had 2 classes.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import keras.utils

#Create train and test data
def create_Xt_Yt(X, y, percentage=0.8):
    p = int(len(X) * percentage)
    X_train = X[0:p]
    Y_train = y[0:p]

    X_test = X[p:]
    Y_test = y[p:]

    return X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['Date'])
df.set_index(['Date'], inplace=True)
df.drop(['Volume'],1, inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
data = df.loc[:, 'AMD-close'].tolist()

window = 30
forecast = 3
forecast_target_long = 1.015 
forecast_target_short= 0.985

x_holder = []
y_holder = []

for i in range(len(data)):
    try:
        x_class = data[i:i+window]
        y_class = data[i+window+forecast]


        window_last_price = data[i+window]
        forecast_price = y_class

        if forecast_price > (window_last_price*forecast_target_long):
            y_class = [1]
        elif forecast_price < (window_last_price*forecast_target_short):
            y_class = [-1]
        else:
            y_class = [0]

        y_holder.append(y_class) 
        x_holder.append(x_class)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        break 

normalize = [(np.array(i) - np.mean(i)) / np.std(i) for i in x_holder] 
y_holder = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_holder, 3)
x_holder, y_holder = np.array(x_holder), np.array(y_holder)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = create_Xt_Yt(x_holder, y_holder)
```

This is the model:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, Adam, SGD, Nadam
from keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau
from keras import regularizers
from keras import losses

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=window, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(16, activity_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01)))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) 



reduce_learning_ontop = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', factor=0.9, patience=25, min_lr=0.000001, verbose=1)
model.compile(Adam(lr=.0001),loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy']) 
myModel = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=160, verbose=1, shuffle=True, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So two thing here:

1. Change activation:

   ```
   model.add(Activation('softmax'))
   ```

   `sigmoid` is designed for binary classification - in case of multiclass classification - `softmax` is the state of the art activation.
2. Change loss:

   ```
   model.compile(
       Adam(lr=.0001),
       loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
   ```

   `binary_crossentropy` is also designed for `binary_classification`. An equivalent to this is `categorical_crossentropy`.